# How to create a name and date stamping workflow?

Tags: workflow, designer, comments

I'm working on creating a form that multiple users can edit.

I'd like a feature where a Name and Time Stamp is added to the comments box when a person modified/edits the filed.

[image]

Is there a way I can add the name and time of modification each time a user edit it?

Comment: you already have a Modified On and Modified column with required information you can just create a calculated field and append them together.

Comment: The workflow above only stamps the name and date once.. is there way I can get it to loop every for every modification?

Comment: You can activate versioning, it will track user, time and details whatever modified.

Comment: @HitendraSolanki is there a way version history can be visible to all users?

Comment: If the user is having read permission he/she will be able to view version history. check this link to understand permission on versioning: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-permissions-do-i-need-for-sharepoint-versioning-95bce34c-db77-4fd4-8449-9ad7ce0363c0

Comment: @HitendraSolanki. Thanks for that! Is there a way I can add the versioning information in a column in the list? Because at the moment, the user will need to right click the item and select "Versions".

Answer (score 0):

Each list item may have multiple versions so I don't think this is possible OOB, you can use JSLink to do so. Or you can create custom view using jQuery HTML.